# Why does bash's tab completion trigger the stack protector?

Tags: bash, gcc, stack

I'm using `bash` 5.0.16 (and `bash-completion` 2.10) on Manjaro. Today, I absentmindedly hit the tab key while moving some files, and was greeted with an unexpected message:

```
[charles@wirepile some_dir]$ mv ~down*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
```

I had to `^C` to regain control of the shell.

It appears that my (up-to-date Manjaro) build of bash triggers the stack protector whenever tab completion is invoked on the tilde character, with or without other characters following it. The following *does* work:

```
[charles@wirepile some_dir]$ ls ~/
.this_dir/                .that_file                 another_file
```

I shouldn't have any unusual lines in my `.bashrc`, unless Manjaro customizes it by default.

I imagine this is some sort of buffer overrun and should be considered a bug -- is it somehow intentional? Should I contact the developers, or the package maintainers?

I'm also curious -- can anyone reproduce this issue?

Comment: Yes, it's a bug. bash shouldn't trigger the stack protector. Also mention if you have the programmable completion enabled (`shopt progcom`) and the `bash-completion` (or similar) package installed.

Answer (score 3):

> is it somehow intentional? Should I contact the developers, or the package maintainers?

Yes, this is a bug. It has been reproduced by numerous others, and was [reported as a bug](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2020-01/msg00002.html) this year (2020-01-06) to the Bash maintainers.

As of my writing this (2020-07-23), no follow-up has been posted so we don't know what the maintainers are doing about it yet.

Comment: Reproduced it today under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with bash 5.0-6ubuntu1.1 and bash-completion 1:2.10-1ubuntu1